# Multiple Base Addresses and Multiple Endpoints in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, base-address

I'm using two bindings TCP and HTTP. I want to give **mex** data on both bindings.
What I want is that the mexHttpBinding only exposes the HTTP services while the mexTcpBinding exposes TCP services only. Or is this possible that I access **stats** service only from HTTP binding and the **eventLogging** service from TCP?

For Example:

- For TCP I should only have

  ```
  net.tcp://localhost:9001/ABC/mex
  net.tcp://localhost:9001/ABC/eventLogging
  ```
- For HTTP

  ```
  http://localhost:9002/ABC/stats
  http://localhost:9002/ABC/mex
  ```

When I connect with any of the base address (using the WCF Test Client) I'm able to access all the services? Like when I connect with ***net.tcp://localhost:9001/ABC*** I'm able to use the services which are offered on the HTTP binding. Why is that so?

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ABCServiceBehavior" name="ABC.Data.DataServiceWCF">
      <endpoint address="eventLogging" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ABC.Campaign.IEventLoggingService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <endpoint address="stats" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ABC.Data.IStatsService" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/ABC" />
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9002/ABC" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ABCServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Quick question, why do you want to separate the tcp and http endpoints mex wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to give mex data on both
>   bindings. What I want is that the
>   mexHttpBinding only exposes the HTTP
>   services while the mexTcpBinding
>   exposes TCP services only. Or is this
>   possible that I access stats service
>   only from HTTP binding and the
>   eventLogging service from TCP?

Well, in this case, you need to have two separate, distinct services - one that exposes `eventLogging` only, and another one that exposes `stats` only.

When you have two separate services, you can expose one over HTTP and its mex will only show those methods, and the other over TCP/IP and expose its methods.

```
<services>
  <service name="ABC.Data.DataServiceWCFEventlogging"
           behaviorConfiguration="ABCServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="eventLogging" 
              binding="netTcpBinding" 
              contract="ABC.Campaign.IEventLoggingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" 
              binding="mexTcpBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/ABC" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>
  </service>
  <service name="ABC.Data.DataServiceWCFStats"
           behaviorConfiguration="ABCServiceBehavior" >
     <endpoint address="stats" 
               binding="basicHttpBinding" 
               contract="ABC.Data.IStatsService" />
     <endpoint address="mex" 
               binding="mexHttpBinding" 
               contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     <host>
        <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9002/ABC" />
        </baseAddresses>
     </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

If you have both methods on the same service, there is no way to expose only parts of it over http and another part over tcp/ip.

Comment: Very helpful. I was misguided about having multiple endpoints in a single service corresponding to multiple endpoints. I elaborated on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115141/why-does-the-wcf-test-client-tool-only-display-a-single-endpoint-baseadress-for-m/6125972#6125972